# How to create a custom component to select time in 30 mins of interval?

Tags: reactjs

I am using react-datetime library. Currently a user can select any time but I do not want this behavior.

[image]

I want a user can only select time in a dropdown with 30 mins of interval. Like this-

[image]

For this I want to create a custom component so that I can use it everywhere in the code.

Here is the current code ->

```
                            <Datetime
                                dateFormat={false}
                                onChange={this.handleStartTime}
                                onBlur={() => this.handleCallStartTime()}
                                value={
                                  session
                                    ? session.startTime
                                    : moment(session.startTime).format('hh:mm a')
                                }
                              />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a time constraint, for example like this:

```
timeConstraints = {
    minutes: {
      step: 30
    }
  }
```

Then change your Datetime component to:

```
<Datetime ... timeConstraints={timeConstraints} />
```

You can find some more info [here in the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datetime) if you search for timeConstraints.